# React Router: Efficient way to access resources with dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
    <Route exact path="/catalog/:id" component={Video} />
</Switch>
```

The **Video** component uses components that are used in different places of the app, if I want to access to resources from children components of **Video** component, I have to use the path *../images*, but if I use those components from another path (like path="/") then I have to use the *./images* path.

To solve this problem I came up with something like this:

```
{this.props.doubleSlash
    ? <img src={'../images/' + assetName}/>
    : <img src={'./images' + assetName} />
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use absolute paths: `/assets/images/' + assetName`

Comment: haha thanks, that worked! The solution was using absolute paths.